# From a MVC View through Javascript, Call a controller, and return a Json result

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I am working on a Single Page Application in MVC4. I have a dropdown box. When I select that drop down box, the onchange event will fire calling some JavaScript.

I need the JavaScript to call the controller and have the controller return a JSON result of some data (I know how to get the data). Could anyone help me get a basic framework laid out for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wire up the onchange javascript event to your select element

In the event function for the onchange, have ajax send the value from the select element to a controller.

In the controller/action method do your work based on the value and then prepare json data (perhaps serialize?) and then return it.

In the success part of the ajax call, parse or otherwise use the returned json data.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller constructor:

```
define('_IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest');
```

Before you load your view check the `_IS_AJAX` variable:

```
if(_IS_AJAX) {
    //echo json_encode(data you want to return);
} else {
    // load view normally
}
```

in your view (using jQuery)

```
$('#dropdownid').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: requesturl,  //your controller URL
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            //Do stuff with data
            }
        },
        error: function(request, error, errormessage) {
            $("#error").html(error + '\n' + errormessage);
        }
    });
});
```